# How to solve casting warning in creating MessageBox

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, mingw

(1) **[Solved!]**

```
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
```

warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

**Solution**

I solved by using

```
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
```

Because I've looked at `IDI_APPLICATION` definition and it is defined as

```
#define IDI_APPLICATION MAKEINTRESOURCE(32512)
```

Weird? *un peu.*

(2) **[solved!]**

```
MessageBox(NULL,
        _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
        _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
        NULL); // < here
```

warning: passing argument 4 of 'MessageBoxW' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: What type is `wcex.hIcon`? Why are you passing NULL when an integer is expected in `MessageBox`?

Comment: For the second one: Say `0`. Never use `NULL` as an integer -- it is not! It's a *pointer*! It doesn't even have to have all its bits equal to zero.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Well, i just copy and paste this code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Comment: @Fabricio: And now you just learned why the MS website is a terrible place for learning how to program! Consider it an API reference, but nothing more than that. You have to bring-your-own-skills.

Comment: @KerrekSB - oh, really? THE LIFE IS A LIE. D:

Comment: I think mingw just broken decades of win32 standards on this one. `LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));` works fine in MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

1) From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072(v=vs.85).aspx)

`To use one of the predefined icons, set the hInstance parameter to NULL and the lpIconName parameter to one of the following values.`

So to use `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION)` as the second argument, the optional first should be `NULL`.

If it's not that... then it's how you're setting the return, `wcex.hIcon` needs to be a pointer, not an `int`. `LoadIcon` returns a `HICON` type, which is a typedef to a `HANDLE` which is a typedef to a `VOIDP` which is a typedef to a `void *`

So if you're doing this:

```
int wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(...)
```

You'd get a `cast from pointer to integer` warning.

2) From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx), the first 3 arguments to the `MessageBox()` are optional, the forth is not. You're passing the forth as NULL when it expects an `UINT`

Comment: To the first, i set NULL, but the warning is there yet. I think there is to do with MAKEINTRESOURCE arg.

Comment: @Fabricio - see my update. I'd suspect it's more the setting of the return value from the `LoadIcon()` function. Can you check that out and update with what type the wcex.hIcon is?